# Why is this simple React Native Flex layout not rendering correctly?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a React Native Component `InnerElement.js` that represents a 2x3 grid made of flex elements. (The height of this `InnerElement` is supposed to remain constant wherever imported.):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class InnerElement extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Hi</Text>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", width: "80%" }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "powderblue" }}>A</Text>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "red" }}>B</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 3, flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>C</Text>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "blue" }}>D</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "red" }}>E</Text>
                        <Text style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "red" }}>F</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

By itself, it displays fine. However, when I import this component into a `ParentScreen.js`, all the elements in the ParentScreen render at random, overlapping, overflowing locations:

```
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import InnerElement from "../elements/InnerElement";


export default function ParentScreen({}) {

    return (
        
        <View style={{  alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>Hello 1</Text>
            <InnerElement />
            <Text>Hello 2</Text>
            <Text>Hello 3</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I'd like all the components to be centered horizontally and rendered in vertical order without overlap. With `alignItems` and `justifyContent`, the `<Text>` elements get dislocated. Without `alignItems` and `justifyContent`, `InnerElement` and `<Text>` are rendered on top of each other.

What am I doing wrong here?